# Specify multiple criteria's in spring mongo db query

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am iterating over a list of key/value pairs and executing find for each key/value. Can I create a single query document to be kind of union in sql, So that there will be only one database call.

```
    List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
    for (Map accounts:attributes) {
        Query query = new Query();
        List<Criteria> andCriteriaList = new ArrayList<Criteria>();
        accounts.forEach((key, value) -> {
            Criteria criteria = Criteria.where((String) key).is(value);
            andCriteriaList.add(criteria);
        });
        query.addCriteria(new Criteria().andOperator(andCriteriaList.toArray(new Criteria[andCriteriaList.size()])));
        if (mongoTemplate.exists(query, User.class)) {
            userList.add((User)mongoTemplate.find(query, User.class));
            //System.out.println(mongoTemplate.find(query, User.class));
        }
```

Thanks,

Comment: You can use the `$in` operator. Something like `Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("UserID").in(userList.stream().map(User::getId).collect(Collectors.toList())));
        List<User> users = mongoTemplate.find(query,User.class);`

Comment: @Veeram, sorry I forgot to mention that the query document will be dynamic in nature and where condition can be different. I provided a more suitable example

Comment: Np.You can always prepare the `Query` object dynamically too from your incoming attributes. I saw the latest update. What problems are you running into while doing that conversion ?

Comment: @Veeram its working, but the query will be called each time for every attribute element. Cant we make it a single query and then send it to the database.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can refactor your code to create `$or` expressions. No explicit `$and` operator needed.

Something like

```
 Query orQuery = new Query();
 Criteria orCriteria = new Criteria();
 List<Criteria> orExpression =  new ArrayList<>();
 for (Map<String, Object> accounts : attributes) {
   Criteria expression = new Criteria();
   accounts.forEach((key, value) -> expression.and(key).is(value));
   orExpression.add(expression);
 }
 orQuery.addCriteria(orCriteria.orOperator(orExpression.toArray(new Criteria[orExpression.size()])));
 List<User> userList = mongoOperations.find(orQuery, User.class);
```

This should output query like

```
{ "$or" : [{ "key1" : "value1", "key2" : "value2" }, { "key3" : "value3", "key4" : "value4" }] }
```

Answer (score 10):

if you want to query multiple fields(field1, field2, ....) with values below is the solution

```
Query query = new Query();
List<Criteria> criteria = new ArrayList<>();

criteria.add(Criteria.where(field1).is(field1val));
criteria.add(Criteria.where(field2).is(field2val));
// you can add all your fields here as above

query.addCriteria(new Criteria().andOperator(criteria.toArray(new Criteria[criteria.size()])));
List<JSONObject> filteredVals = mongoOperations.find(query, JSONObject.class);
```

the above return filteredVals is JSONObject