# Need help tuning my mongotemplate query as it is taking 6-7 seconds

Tags: json, spring, mongotemplate

I am new to MongoDB. The following query is taking a very long time - how might I tune it so that it gets a list of the records rather than hitting MongoDB multiple times?

```
List newList = new ArrayList ();
listDetails.forEach(query -> {
    BasicDBObject  criteria1 = new BasicDBObject();
    criteria1.put("_id", query.getId());
    BasicDBObject criteria2 = new BasicDBObject();
    criteria2 .put("$elemMatch", new BasicDBObject("ID", query.getEmpId()));
    BasicQuery basicQuery = new BasicQuery(criteria1, new BasicDBObject("empName", criteria2));
    newList.add(mongoTemplate.findOne(basicQuery, ClassName.class));
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specify multiple criteria's in spring mongo db query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45719225/specify-multiple-criterias-in-spring-mongo-db-query)

Comment: Hi @Veeram i am bit confused with the answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45719225/specify-multiple-criterias-in-spring-mongo-db-query Can you please modify and give me the logic for my requirement ? Thanks in advance!!