# Aggregation with multiple criteria

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework, mongotemplate

I want to perform aggregation using multiple criteria. The problem is that I don't know how to pass multiple criteria. Do I declare multiple Match operation like below?

```
MatchOperation matchOperation1 = Aggregation.match(criteria);
MatchOperation matchOperation2 = Aggregation.match(criteria2);
```

And if yes, then how do I pass them to the aggregation method? I thought that it should be possible to create a MatchOperation that adheres in multiple criteria but I have not found such an example online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I declare multiple Match operation like below?
>
> ```
> MatchOperation matchOperation1 = Aggregation.match(criteria); 
> MatchOperation matchOperation2 = Aggregation.match(criteria2);
> ```

The `Criteria` class has an `and` method, which allows combining two conditions. For example, consider the three documents:

```
{ _id: 1, size: 10, color: "blue" }
{ _id: 2, size: 12, color: "red" }
{ _id: 3, size: 8, color: "blue" }
```

The aggregation `match` stage is defined as follows:

```
Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("size").gt(new Integer(8))
                            .and("color").is("blue")
)
```

This returns the document with `_id: 1`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use list of `criteria` in `MatchOperation` , when you want filter dynamically:

```java
List<Criteria> criterias = new ArrayList<>();
for (String key : mongoRequest.getFilterQuery().keySet()) {
                Criteria ci= new Criteria();
                List<Object> listOfValues=new ArrayList<>();
                for(Object value:mongoRequest.getFilterQuery().get(key)){
                    listOfValues.add(value);
                }
                ci = Criteria.where(key).in(listOfValues);
                criterias.add(ci);
           }
MatchOperation match =new MatchOperation(!criterias.isEmpty()?new Criteria().andOperator(criterias.toArray(new Criteria[criterias.size()])):new Criteria());
```

you can also refer this link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45723850/9450155).

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
final Criteria firstMatchCriteria = Criteria.where("fielname").is(someValue)
final Criteria secondMatchCriteria = Criteria.where("fielname").is(someValue)
final Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(        match(firstMatchCriteria),unwind("FIELD_"),match(secondMatchCriteria),project())
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a better solution

```
Criteria result = criteria1.andOperator(criteria2, cri2teria,......)
```

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me after all.

```
    Criteria criterias = new Criteria().andOperator(Criteria.where(Force.AMOUNT).gte(minForceAmount)
            .and(ForceType.TYPE).is(ForceTypeEnum.MAGNETIC_FORCE)
            .and("createdAt").gte(startDate).lte(endDate));
    MatchOperation matchOperation = Aggregation.match(criteria);
```